# Python Beautifulsoup Request variants

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I solved a lot of my issues with stackoverflow.

Today, I decided to ask my question.
I'm new learning Python. I'm looking at how to scrape data from the web.

I came to an example of website where products may have different variants in term of size or colour.
I can't figure out how 'follow' the link to reach the page of the variant. I can see that there is a call to a function but I don't know how to have access to this function/link.

See below urls as examples:

[variant of colour and size](https://www.completecareshop.co.uk/bedroom-aids/chairs/chair-booster-cushions/black-harley-booster-cushion-high-small?sku=Q01062)

[variant of colour](https://www.completecareshop.co.uk/bedroom-aids/chairs/single-motor-riser-recliner-chairs/indiana-rise-and-recline-chair-biscuit?sku=M85668):

Here is the code I use to get all the variants available but it's not working as I want and finally I don't know how to get the links:

```
# Define the part of the page I'm interested in:
article = soup.find('header', class_='pdp-header')

for variant in article.find_all('p', class_='pdp-size-variants__title'): 
    print(variant)
    if "Colour" in variant:
        for colours in article.find('div', class_='swatches__item'):
            print(colours)
    if "Size" in variant:
        for sizes in article.find('button', class_='btn-supportive'):
            print(sizes)
```

The result, I have is:

```
<p class="pdp-size-variants__title small--xs mb-1"><strong>Colour</strong></p>
<p class="pdp-size-variants__title small--xs mb-1"><strong>Size</strong></p>
```

If you can put me on the right direction that would be great.

Thanks a lot.

David

Answer (score 1):

> I can see that there is a call to a function but I don't know how to have access to this function/link.

The first step is to look at that function. Start by looking at the swatch:

```
<div class="swatches__item"><span title="Black" onclick="getProductVariantFunc(12145,267721)" class="swatch active" style="background-image:url('https://ccshop.sirv.com/ccs/images/swatches/Black.png');background-size:100%"> </span></div>
```

Here we see there is an `onclick` handler named `getProductVariantFunc`. Now you should open up the page source and find the code for that function:

```
<script>function getProductVariantFunc(n, t) {
    $("#product-variants").addClass("disabled-div");
    t !== 0 ? $.ajax({
        cache: !1,
        url: "/VariantAttributes/GetProductHtmlByAttributes",
        type: "POST",
        data: {attributeId: t, productId: n},
        success: function (n) {
            $("#product-info").html(n);
            $("#product-variants").removeClass("disabled-div");
            initProductDetails();
            initPdp();
            renderRecommendedProductList()
        }
    }) : $.ajax({
        cache: !1,
        url: "/VariantAttributes/GetProductHtml",
        type: "POST",
        data: {productId: n},
        success: function (n) {
            $("#product-info").html(n);
            $("#product-variants").removeClass("disabled-div");
            initProductDetails();
            initPdp();
            renderRecommendedProductList()
        }
    })
}</script>
```

We can see here that the page makes an `ajax()` call to the URL `"/VariantAttributes/GetProductHtmlByAttributes"`. So all you have to do is request that same URL to see if it has the data you need.